# how to separate value from FormCollection ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wanna Add new multi records to databese,
and I design View have multi form to filed data and insert it.

My View have:
--item 1
  `@Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.Description)`...
.
.
.
--item 2
  `@Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.Description)`...

I use

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection c)
        {
 var desc = c.GetValue("item.Description");

}
```

I use it do get value, but I wanna separate  value of desc.
I use `.Split(',');` but if desc has value :

> "test value, test desc"

So I can't use it.

So Anyone tell me. how to loop item to insert it

Comment: Use model binding instead.

Comment: can u tell me in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use -

```
Request.Form["Your property Name"]
```

**WORKING CODE:**

Model -

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

View -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitData","Post", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MyClass</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

On POST, you can access it like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitData(MyClass c)
{
    var name = Request.Form["MyName"];
    return View();

}
```

We will have the input value in the name variable. Check below image.
[image]

Also in the above code I showed how to do model binding too. If you use variable 'c', that will also have value from UI. Check below image.
[image]

Comment: I realize this is quite a bit old, but I'm sure glad I found it. I was passing values using formcollection and couldn't understand why some values were passing and others weren't. Using the model binding name "Request.Form["Your property Name"]" rather the ID name solved my problem. THANK YOU!.

Answer (score 1):

You could prefix the id's of the fields so that you can retrieve the two separate fields;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty, new { @id = "item_1_description" });
```

And that would allow you to get that specific value from the FormCollection;

```
string description = c.GetValue("item_1_description");
```

However, it would be cleaner if you could take advantage of [strongly-typing your views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views). In your position, I would create a `ViewModel` that represents both of your objects. Since I don't know what your data types are, I'll use the example of a Person, which looks like this;

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To to add two people in one form, you would create a `ViewModel' that represents what the form would look like - a flattened version of two people;

```
public class MuliplePeopleViewModel
{
  public string Person1Name { get; set; }
  public string Person2Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which would generate a view with two textboxes;

```
@model MuliplePeopleViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Person1Name);
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Person2Name);
```

Now in your `Controller` you can replace your use of `FormCollection` with our new `ViewModel`, that will automatically bind the values of the TextBox's to the relevant properties;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MuliplePeopleViewModel viewModel)
{
  string person1Name = viewModel.Person1Name;
}
```

Food for thought: I'm not entirely sure the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind an unflattened version of the `ViewModel`, such as;

```
public class MuliplePeopleViewModel
{
  public Person Person1 { get; set; }
  public Person Person2 { get; set; }
}
```

But perhaps you could try it!

**EDIT**

Following comments from the author, you could also create a `ViewModel` that contains an `ICollection<Person>`;

```
public class MuliplePeopleViewModel
{
  public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

And in your view you can loop through the collection and display fields for each;

```
@model MuliplePeopleViewModel

@foreach (Person person in Model.People)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(x => person.Name);
}
```

Now, the `DefaultModelBinder` should now give you a list of people to use in your action. However, if not, you may need to write a [custom model binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder).

More food for thought: You might be able to [utilise EditorTemplates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) to simplify your view.

Let me know if I can help further.

Matt

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can do it now with your Answers.

Comment: But Do you have another solution?, If I Wanna Insert/Update multi Person,and I do not know how much Person before. So I don't know,I declare how many variables.

Comment: @VuongNguyen Can I ask why this answer has been unaccepted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection c, string[] description)
{

}
```

So you will have the values in an array.